# Deleting Empty Rows/Nodes

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to delete the empty rows in a table. I traversed to those empty rows. But I don't know how to delete that particular node. I tried to traverse to the parent node and delete, but somehow it seems to show error.
`empr[e].removeChild(empr[e].rows[et])` I used this inside the for loop

```js
function emptyrows() {
  var count = 0;
  var empr = document.getElementsByClassName("tide");
  var emlen = document.getElementsByClassName("tide").length;

  alert(emlen);
  for (var e = 0; e < emlen; e++) {
    var emtab = empr[e].rows.length;
    for (var et = 0; et < emtab; et++) {
      if (empr[e].rows[et].innerHTML == "") {

      } else {
        console.log("Nothing Empty");
      }
    }

  }

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Barry</td>
      <td>
        <table class="tide">
          <tr>50</tr>
          <tr>10</tr>
          <tr>200</tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Allen</td>
      <td>
        <table class="tide">
          <tr>50</tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>
        <table class="tide">
          <tr>50</tr>
          <tr>20</tr>
          <tr></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your HTML is semantically incorrect. `tr` must have `td`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, however you need to correct your HTML to be semantic (include  inside ). But the code below should give you the general idea on how to proceed:

```
function emptyrows() {
    var tables = document.getElementsByClassName("tide");
    for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
            if (tables[i].childNodes[j].innerHTML === '') {
                tables[i].removeChild(tables[i].childNodes[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

emptyrows();
```